# Can browse sysvol but not netlogon with Samba 4.1.5-SerNet-RedHat-7.el6 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: active-directory, file-permissions, samba4, netlogon, centos6.5

I have three servers: a Win2003 box running as the first AD DC, a 64-bit CentOS 6.5 box running Samba 4.1.5 x64 in AD DC mode, and a 32-bit CentOS 6.5 box running the same version of everything but 32-bit, also configured for AD DC mode.

Except for the 64-bit box's extra shares, the two CentOS boxes have identical `smb.conf`, `krb5.conf`, and `resolv.conf` files, and are both up-to-date via `yum update`.

From the Win2003 box, I can navigate in Explorer to `\\64bitbox\`, and it shows `netlogon` and `sysvol` and I can go into both of them.  If I navigate to `\\32bitbox\` it shows both, and I can drill all the way through `sysvol` to the same level as the files that should be in `netlogon`, but trying to go into `netlogon` directly gives this error:

```
--------------------------- 
\\32bitbox
--------------------------- 
\\32bitbox\netlogon is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource.
Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

Incorrect function.

--------------------------- 
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have gone through all my notes from setting up the 64-bit box and cannot figure out what I've done differently with the 32-bit box that might cause this.  I've reset ownership and permissions on both folders, the entire hierarchy from `sysvol` down looks identical both in Windows and from the Linux `ls -Ral sysvol` command (in terms of both owners and perms, every last entry) on each server.  (In particular, the `Administrators` group I'm part of has Full Control, and `Authenticated Users` have read/exec/list Windows ACLs.)  `smb.conf` looks like this on the 32-bit box (and the 64-bit box just has additional share sections afterwards):

```
[global]
        workgroup = MYDOM
        realm = mydom.lan
        server role = active directory domain controller
        server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, s3fs, dns
        allow dns updates = secure
        dns forwarder = 10.0.0.1
        dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, wkssvc, rpcecho, samr, netlogon, lsarpc, spoolss, drsuapi, dssetup, unixinfo, browser, eventlog6, backupkey, dnsserver
        interfaces = lo eth0

# trying to get rid of CUPS errors in /var/log/messages
load printers = no
printcap name = /dev/null
disable spoolss = yes

read only = No
force create mode = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
inherit acls = yes
inherit owner = yes
mangle prefix = 6

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydom.lan/scripts
        admin users = me
        profile acls = no

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        admin users = me
        profile acls = no
```

Furthermore, running `smbclient //32bitbox/netlogon -k -c 'ls'` from either CentOS box gives me a correct file listing with no errors, and this is directly after a `kinit me`, where `me` is the same username I'm logged into the Win2003 box as when I get the above error trying to browse `\\32bitbox\netlogon`.

What else might cause the error I'm getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Samba 4.1.6 seemed to fix the issue.  I can now browse to `netlogon` from the Win2003 box.  However, it's also possible that it was a problem on the Win2003 end, because that box ended up being restarted before the upgrade, and I hadn't thought of that until after upgrading.